# Sci-fi book in which aliens arrive through a portal and start a war with humans

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-invasion

In the book, aliens appear through a portal and then attack humans, but they fight back and go through the portal with a weaponized moon.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, if you recall any other details about the book, please [edit] them into your question. The more info you can provide, the greater the likelihood that someone can ID this for you.

Answer (score 6):

Possibly the [*Troy Rising*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/51166-troy-rising) series by John Ringo

> When aliens trundled a gate to other worlds into the solar system, the world reacted with awe, hope and fear. But the first aliens to come through, the Glatun, were peaceful traders and the world breathed a sigh of relief.
>
> When the Horvath came through, they announced their ownership by dropping rocks on three cities and gutting them. Since then, they've held Terra as their own personal fiefdom. With their control of the orbitals, there's no way to win and earth's governments have accepted the status quo.
>
> *Live Free or Die* - The first book
>
> To free the world from the grip of the Horvath is going to take an unlikely hero. A hero unwilling to back down to alien or human governments, unwilling to live in slavery and with enough hubris, if not stature, to think he can win. Fortunately, there's Tyler Vernon. And he has bigger plans than just getting rid of the Horvath.

This involves inflating a giant asteroid (scientific explanation is in the books) which is then kitted out with giant beam weapons and missiles.

This giant weaponised asteroid passes through the portal in the third book, *The Hot Gate*